# omit the json response title in json body result in php

Tags: php, json

I have the json response like this from fetching via URL, using json_decode.

```
function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 3;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$domain = "http://localhost:3000/";

$getcontent = get_data($domain);
$data = json_decode($getcontent, true);
```

After fetched, the response is:

```
{"Data":{"Players":"2,621","Kills":"87","Medals":"908","Cards":"324","TimePlayed":"88hours","GamesWon":"328","ObjectiveTime":"05:25:02"}}
```

I would like to remove `Data` object to be just the response body in PHP.

I have tried: `$data[0]['Players'];` but it is not looking through the json data body.

```
$players = $data[0]['Players'];
```

So I display it as:

```
echo 'Players: ' . $players . ';
```

Note: Sometimes that `Data` will always changed dynamic like `Responses`, `Players`, `PlayerName`, `Date`.

Can I use `$data['. $playername . ']["Player"];` ?

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: @SahilGulati There's no response from that.

Comment: I want to know what you want from this above `JSON`?

Comment: @SahilGulati I just want to display the Players value.

Comment: Do `$data['Data']['Players']` to get the players, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: You just `print_r($data["Data"]["Players"]);`

Comment: @SahilGulati What if the "Data" will always be changed? Sometimes it is "Data", "Response", "Date", etc. It has like 30+ different naming.

Comment: @rishipuri What if the "Data" will always be changed? Sometimes it is "Data", "Response", "Date", etc. It has like 30+ different naming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the `key` you can use [key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) function of `PHP`. Whatever the value of your first `key` you can access it like this.

[**Try this code demo**](https://eval.in/790298)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='{"Data":{"Players":"2,621","Kills":"87","Medals":"908","Cards":"324","TimePlayed":"88hours","GamesWon":"328","ObjectiveTime":"05:25:02"}}';

$array=json_decode($string,true);

print_r($array[key($array)]["Players"]);
```

**Solution 2:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/790311)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='{"Data":{"Players":"2,621","Kills":"87","Medals":"908","Cards":"324","TimePlayed":"88hours","GamesWon":"328","ObjectiveTime":"05:25:02"}}';

$array=json_decode($string,true);


extract($array[key($array)]);
echo $Players;
echo $Kills;
echo $Medals;
echo $Cards;
echo $TimePlayed;
echo $GamesWon;
echo $ObjectiveTime;
```

**Whole code:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 3;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$domain = "http://localhost:3000/";
$getcontent = get_data($url);
$data = json_decode($getcontent, true);

print_r($data[key($data)]["Players"]);
```

Comment: But I have got an error: Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: @KyrosKoh You must supply an array to key function, make sure you have `json_decode` try this code snippet https://eval.in/790298

Comment: @SahilGultai It has already declared, as posted in the question.

Comment: @SahilGultai I want to assign each value like this:

$Players = $result[key($result)]['Players'];

Comment: @KyrosKoh If you want to assign each value like this you can do that.

Comment: The values of $Players, $Kills are assigned automatically like that? What if the values are long and I need to assign with another values such as:

$PlayerName = $Player-Name

Note: $Player-Name is from the response.

Comment: @KyrosKoh You can do it like after extract statement you can use `$Player_Name=$PlayerName;` `-` are not allowed.

Comment: Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array
Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array.

I got this warning

Comment: So how to handle the data with - in it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143757/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-kyros-koh).